# Lost potential energy?

Tags: electrostatics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, antimatter

If there are two electrons and a positron are in an closed system (not being influenced by gravity) all these  have electromagnetic potential energy  amongst them . if one of the electron then touches the positron and anhilated. Where is the potential energy of the remaining electron now?

Answer (score 2):

The remaining electron feels a potential from the other two. Just before annihilation, those two are next to each other, and so the potential from them at the remaining electron is zero. After annihilation, it is still zero. So: no potential energy lost.